# hibernate projection NumberFormatException for input string

Tags: spring, hibernate, projection, hibernate-criteria, numberformatexception

## **I am using Spring MVC + Hibernate**

**Generic Dao**

```
// getAll
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass) throws DataAccessException {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

**@Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/genCompanyInfoUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String genCompanyInfoUpdate(Model model) {

    List<GenCountryModel> countryList=pt.getAll(GenCountryModel.class);
    List<GenCurrencyModel> currencyList=pt.getAll(GenCurrencyModel.class);

    GenCompanyInfoModel companyInfo=pt.getById(GenCompanyInfoModel.class, 1);

    model.addAttribute("countryList", countryList);
    model.addAttribute("currencyList", currencyList);
    model.addAttribute("companyInfo", companyInfo);

    return "gen/genCompanyInfoUpdate";
}
```

**JSP**

```
<c:if test="${not empty currencyList}">
    <c:forEach items="${currencyList}" var="get" varStatus="counter">
    <ct:Options setValue="${get.id}" setName="${get.isoCode}" selected="${companyInfo.genCurrencyModel.id}" setState="1" />
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

All working well but when I change and use Projection in Method as the following , then it give exception

```
java.lang.numberformatexception for input string id 
java.lang.numberformatexception for input string isoCode
```

**Changes: ProjectionList use in Method**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass, String[] nameList) throws DataAccessException {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);

ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();

    for (int i=0; i<nameList.length; i++) {
        pl.add(Projections.property(nameList[i].toString()));   
    }

    criteria.setProjection(pl);

    return criteria.list();
}
```

**Changes in @Controller passing List [GenCurrencyModel]**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/genCompanyInfoUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String genCompanyInfoUpdate(Model model) {

    String []list={"id","isoCode"};

    List<GenCountryModel> countryList=pt.getAll(GenCountryModel.class);
    List<GenCurrencyModel> currencyList=pt.getAll(GenCurrencyModel.class,list);

    GenCompanyInfoModel companyInfo=pt.getById(GenCompanyInfoModel.class, 1);

    model.addAttribute("countryList", countryList);
    model.addAttribute("currencyList", currencyList);
    model.addAttribute("companyInfo", companyInfo);

    return "gen/genCompanyInfoUpdate";
}
```

**Same JSP**

```
<c:if test="${not empty currencyList}">
    <c:forEach items="${currencyList}" var="get" varStatus="counter">
    <ct:Options setValue="${get.id}" setName="${get.isoCode}" selected="${companyInfo.genCurrencyModel.id}" setState="1" />
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

**GenCurrencyModel**

```
public class GenCurrencyModel implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@Column(name = "CURRENCYID")
@GeneratedValue
private long id;


@Column(name = "CODE")
private String currencyCode;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String currencyDesc;

@Column(name = "ISACTIVE")
private int isActive;

@Column(name = "MADELETE")
private int markAsDelete;

@Column(name = "ISOCODE")
private String isoCode;

@Column(name = "CURRENCYUNIT")
private String currencyUnit;

@Column(name = "CONNECTOR")
private String connector;

@Column(name = "SUBUNIT")
private String subUnit;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERID")
private long recentUserId;

@Column(name = "RECENTUSERIP")
private String recentUserIp;

@Column(name = "DATETIME")
private Date dateTime;

@Column(name = "ISUPDATED")
private int isUpdated;

private GenCompanyInfoModel genCompanyInfoModel;


public GenCurrencyModel() {
    super();
}

//Getter Setter
```

}

**I check the query from log file . it successfully execute**

**and when I remove the following line from jsp page, then there is no any exception**

```
<ct:Options setValue="${get.id}" setName="${get.isoCode}"
```

**Note: ct:Options is a custom JSP tag, that just print values, nothing special**

**After Projection the result of query is as follow**

```
Hibernate: select this_.CURRENCYID as y0_, this_.ISOCODE as y1_ from GENCURRENCY this_
```

**and both returning the list , and I have check both of size(), the size is also same !**

Update me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when using a projection list of specific properties in Hibernate, you won't be able to cast the query result as an entity type, at least not in the older versions of Hibernate I'm familiar with (i.e. 3.2.x). Instead, the default return type will be a `List<Object[]>` (when calling `Criteria#list`), where each array represents a tuple of the properties you specified in the projection list. (You can tell Hibernate to change the return type by giving the `Criteria` a `ResultTransformer`, but that may cause more confusion.) So instead of expecting partially-hydrated entities of type `T` and calling its getter methods (via JSTL expression), expect an array of `Object`s and get each property value by index (based on the order of the properties in the projection list).

Otherwise, it appears that you're passing the string values `"id"` and `"isoCode"` to your `ct` tag library (instead of the `id` and `isoCode` field values that you want), which I assume is expecting strings that can be parsed into numbers using something like `Integer#parseInt(String)`, and this is causing the `NumberFormatException`s.

If this doesn't help, can you please provide more information? Specifically:

- What are the property names you're specifying in the projection list?
- What object types are those properties mapped as in the entity class? Providing the full entity mapping would help.
- Is the `ct:Options` a custom JSP tag? If so, can you provide the logic of the tag class?

Comment: I have edited the post ! may it clear to you. why in second case , there is an exception. but the first case working fine. actually projection should not change the structure of returning... If structure change how control this in spring MVC ? I can not understand the reason of exception

Comment: Again Edit : Also Provide GenCurrencyModel Class

Comment: Can you add the following lines to your controller method and post the output?

`System.out.println("First element of currencyList has type: "+currencyList.get(0).getClass());`
`System.out.println("Id value of first element in currencyList is: "+((GenCurrencyModel)currencyList.get(0)).getId());`

Comment: Without Projection: `First element of currencyList has type: class com.soft.erp.gen.model.GenCurrencyModel
Id value of first element in currencyList is: 1` but with projection `nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.soft.erp.gen.model.GenCurrencyModel]`

Comment: So the one with the projection is returning `List<Object[]>`. You could possibly work around this manually in the dao with code like:

`List<Object[]> l = (List<Object[]>) criteria.list();`
`List<GenCurrencyModel> c = new ArrayList<GenCurrencyModel>();`
`for(Object[] tuple : l) {`
`  GenCurrencyModel m = new GenCurrencyModel();`

Comment: Sorry, finishing previous comment:You could try to use a ResultTransformer or possibly work around this manually in the dao with code like:

`List<Object[]> l = (List<Object[]>) criteria.list();`

`List<GenCurrencyModel> c = new ArrayList<GenCurrencyModel>();`

`for(Object[] tuple : l) {`

`  GenCurrencyModel m = new GenCurrencyModel();`

`  m.setId(((Long) tuple[0]).longValue());`

`  m.setIsoCode((String) tuple[1]);`

`  c.add(m);`

`}`

`return c;`

But this is obviously not dynamic and may have implications for the entity objects if the Hibernate Session remains open.

Comment: why this behave like ! because `criteria.setProjection(pl)` basically return the criteria , which result should be the same as `criteria use without projection`. Thank for pointing the root cause ! fabulous

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31223/discussion-between-shahid-ghafoor-and-supereb)